# How to modify a struct object that is typed Any in Swift?

Tags: swift, struct

Is there a way to modify the `x` property of `unknown` in the following piece of code?

```
struct S {
    var x = 3
}

var s = S()

var unknown: Any = s
```

`unknown` is of type Any and a copy of `s`. While `x` of `s` can be modified by something likes `s.x = 4`, how can one modify the `x` of `unknown`?

Comment: Your code is not very meaningful. If you know that `unknown` is a copy of `s` then you know the type and the explicit (unnecessary) type annotation causes the problem.

Comment: you can typecast it using `as` e.g. `unknown as? S`

Comment: @vadian No, my code is indeed not very useful in the sense that it doesn't really have any practical use. I wrote to code so that I can ask a question in Swift. I want to know if I can change a property of a struct object when it is typed Any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, I think modifying `x` of `unknown` directly is not possible in Swift and it doesn't has to be. After all, a struct object typed `Any` is always a copy of another object, there seems to be no need to modify the internals of such a copy for doing so doesn't modify the original.

I will mark this post as the answer to my question so that future readers will understand the situation clearly, but I will also up-vote all answers that are worthy of consideration.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a conditional binding:

```
if var s = unknown as? S {
    s.x = 4
    unknown = s
}
else {
    print("unknown is not an S")
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted. I want to find a way to change the `x` in the `unknown` object. The code above only changes a copy of `unknown`, not `unknown` itself.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed a step: reassign `s` back to `unknown`.

Comment: Is there a way to modify `unknown` directly, instead of assigning it another value?

Comment: @candleindark I don't think so, no. The reassignment is most likely elided though.

Comment: Not possible, unfortunately. Its properties aren't accessible as `Any` and casting it as `S` (not to a copy) makes it immutable.  You'd have to use a class instead of a struct to modify it directly.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery By casting it to S, do you mean this `(unknown as! S)`?

Comment: @candleindark Probably, but that still doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: @Alexander No, it doesn't. The compiler seems to recognized `(unknown as! S).x` as an immuntable expression. Are there any documentation specifying modification of a struct object typed as Any impossible?

Comment: @candleindark Not that I know of, and there likely isn't, because this isn't something you would (almost) ever need to do

Comment: @candleindark Why are you working with an `Any` variable in the first place?

Comment: @Alexander I agree with you that this is something I possible never need to do however.

Comment: @Alexander I am not actually working with `Any` for any particular task. This has been a hypothetical question from the very beginning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142026/discussion-between-alexander-and-candleindark).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify a use case, but the only reason I can think of for doing this is if you wanted to be able to assign multiple different structs to `unknown`.  In that case, a protocol might do what you need:

```
protocol HasX {
    var x: Int {get set}
}

struct S: HasX {
    var x = 3
}

var s = S()

var unknown: HasX = s

unknown.x = 4 // no error
```

This will limit you to only the properties required by `HasX`, but it's the only way I can think of to accomplish this without using a class.

Answer (score 0):

Make a type cast:
(unknown as S).x = 4

Comment: Doing so is an error.  "Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Int'"

Comment: I don't really know such an error. Try as? instead of as

Comment: I tried `(unknown as? S)!.x = 4`. It generates the same error.

Comment: I tried `(unknown as! S).x = 4`. It generates the same error as well.

Comment: The last thing that may work is (unknown as? S)?.x = 4